# substringBetween() returns null when trying to extract <html>..</html>

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I am building a small Java application to fetch five Wikipedia pages and find substrings in the html source code. I am using the library org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils. However a Wikipedia article can be big, and there seems to be a limitation in StringUtils:

```
String html;

try {
    html = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada").get().html();
} catch(IOException e) {
    html = "";
}

String trimmedHtml = substringBetween(html, "<html>", "</html>");

System.out.println(html); // prints the whole source code fine
System.out.println(trimmedHtml); // prints null
```

Why does the console print `null` for `trimmedHtml`? The output should be (almost) as big as for `html`. Is there a maximum length for the string output or for the parameters of `substringBetween()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string util methods *work* and are *well tested* - there is no "limitation" or "bug" here.

Viewing the page source reveals that `<html>` will not match:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="client-nojs">
```

A great example of why string processing of HTML is *not* a good idea in general. Keep using the support offered by Jsoup, which might be using the [html()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#html()) method after obtaining the <HTML> element.